# Chrome Manifest v3 block redirect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

The scenario is that on a given page, I want to block the browser from redirecting the user to a different page via a chrome extension on manifest v3.

I am listening to redirect events via [onBeforeRedirect](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#event-onBeforeRedirect), but the blocking version of webRequest seems to be deprecated in manifest v3. Chrome seems to recommend [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) instead, but the rules seem much more rigid.

For example, if I wanted to stop a redirect to google.com, I could add a rule like:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "priority": 1,
  "action" : { "type" : "block" },
  "condition" : {
    "urlFilter" : "abc",
    "domains" : ["google.com"],
    "resourceTypes" : ["script"]
  }
}
```

but I still wanted the user to be able visit google.com if they weren't being redirected there. This will block all attempts to go to google.com.

How can I block only redirect events to a given site?

Comment: Apparently there's no way now. You can try using a non-blocking webRequest listener and then inject `stop()` code into the tab, however MV3 is still bugged as hell so webRequest is unusable as the service worker won't wake up.

Comment: I actually gave this a shot yesterday, it didn't work. It stopped at the start of redirected page unfortunately. I hope they make a way to handle this in mv3!

Comment: They won't if you don't report the problem on http://crbug.com...